# Need sorting method for coordinated, flattenned collection

Tags: c#

I have a component which outputs an ICollection of the following type:

```
public class CoordinatedInjectableValue
{
    public int XOffset { get; set; }

    public int YOffset { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is used to describe what is basically a dataset, so for a given XOffset value, the "Value" property of all these objects will be of the same type (int, string, etc). The Value property is always a built-in type, not a custom type.

My challenge is that I would like to use this collection to build up a kind of dataset structure which allows sorting on the columns.

As an example, if I had a collection which looked like this:

```
new List<CoordinatedInjectableValue>
{
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 0, Value = 20},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 1, Value = 10},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 2, Value = 30},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 0, Value = "CCC"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 1, Value = "BBB"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 2, Value = "AAA"}
};
```

I want some method so I can reorder based on the first "column" (ie, where XOffset = 0), so that the collection would then look like this:

```
new List<CoordinatedInjectableValue>
{
    // Ordered by value where XOffset = 0
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 0, Value = 10}, 
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 1, Value = 20},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 2, Value = 30},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 0, Value = "BBB"}, // Note this has also been re-ordered
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 1, Value = "CCC"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 2, Value = "AAA"}
}
```

And if I ordered by the second column (XOffset = 1) then the following would happen:

```
new List<CoordinatedInjectableValue>
{
    // Ordered by value where XOffset = 1
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 0, Value = 30}, // Note this has also been re-ordered
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 1, Value = 10},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 2, Value = 20},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 0, Value = "AAA"}, 
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 1, Value = "BBB"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 2, Value = "CCC"}
};
```

As you can imagine, I'm having some difficulty doing this, even for single-level sorting. I haven't even tried implementing multi level sorting (eg, sort by this, then that).

I am looking for some kind of logical approach to this. I'd rather not have to change the component which returns this data, as it's supplied by a third party, and would be costly for us to change.

Comment: LINQ OrderBy ThenBy ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: @Blam Thanks for your comment - not sure I explained correctly, but I need to re-order by Value property, within the context of a single "column" (ie a set of values with the same XOffset value), which then needs to re-order the other "columns"

Comment: No you did not explain it very well.  How is that not OrderBy(x => x.Offset).ThenBy(y => y.Value)

Comment: @Blam Because I don't want to order by XOffset. I want to order by whatever the Value property is set to. I will update my question.

Comment: Breaks if the group size of offset is not equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just a sorting problem. You are also updating the *YOffset* values based on the sorting. So assume the input data is valid(i.e. no missing offsets, consistent type of Value property). Here is the code:

Source data:

```
var givenList = new List<CoordinatedInjectableValue>
{
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 0, Value = 20},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 1, Value = 10},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 0, YOffset = 2, Value = 30},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 0, Value = "CCC"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 1, Value = "BBB"},
    new CoordinatedInjectableValue {XOffset = 1, YOffset = 2, Value = "AAA"}
};
```

LINQ:

```
var sortedByFirstColumn = givenList
.GroupBy(v => v.YOffset)
.OrderBy(grp => grp.First(x => x.XOffset == 0).Value)
.SelectMany((grp, i) =>
    grp.Select(v => new CoordinatedInjectableValue
    {
        XOffset = v.XOffset,
        YOffset = i,
        Value = v.Value
    }))
```

Verify the result:

```
sortedByFirstColumn
.OrderBy(v => v.XOffset)
.ThenBy(v => v.YOffset)
.ToList()
.ForEach(v => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", v.XOffset, v.YOffset, v.Value));
```

The output:

```
0   0   10
0   1   20
0   2   30
1   0   BBB
1   1   CCC
1   2   AAA
```

Note: I kept sortedByFirstColumn as IEnumerable and unordered, but adjust it the way how your application requires.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CIVComparer : IComparer<CoordinatedInjectableValue>
{
    private string SortBy { get; set; }
    private bool SortAscending { get; set; }

    public CIVComparer()
    {
        SortBy = "default";
        SortAscending = true;
    }

    public CIVComparer(string sortBy, bool sortAscending)
    {
        SortBy = sortBy;
        SortAscending = sortAscending;
    }

    #region IComparer<CoordinatedInjectableValue> Members

    int IComparer<CoordinatedInjectableValue>.Compare(CoordinatedInjectableValue x, CoordinatedInjectableValue y)
    {
        CoordinatedInjectableValue cx, cy;
        if (SortAscending)
        {
            cx = x;
            cy = y;
        }
        else
        {
            cx = y;
            cy = x;
        }
        int result = 0;
        var useCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        string xCaseNum, yCaseNum;

        switch (SortBy)
        {
            case "XOffset":
                result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.XOffset, cy.XOffset);
                if (result == 0) { result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.Value, cy.Value); }
                if (result == 0) { result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(xCaseNum, yCaseNum); }
                break;

            case "Value":
                result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.Value, cy.Value);
                if (result == 0) { result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.XOffset, cy.XOffset); }
                if (result == 0) { result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.YOffset, cy.YOffset); }
                break;

            case "default":
            default:
                result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.YOffset, cy.YOffset);
                if (result == 0) { result = new Comparer(useCulture).Compare(cx.XOffset, cy.XOffset); }
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, when you want to sort a list:

```
    List<CoordinatedInjectableValue> CIVs = MethodWhichReturnsList(argsForMethod);
    CIVComparer civComparer = new CIVComparer(sortBy, sortAscending);
    CIVs.Sort(civComparer);
```

The logic in the Comparer will obviously be different, but, as you can see, it provides a lot of flexibility.